# How can I rotate the view while using another tool (like extrude) in 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view

Add any object, select a face and press E to extrude.
Now try to rotate the view while extruding.
Normally middle mouse does this but while extruding middle mouse does not work.
How do I use the mouse to rotate the view WHILE using extrude (or anything else).

Comment: I don't think that is supported, at least for the time being

Answer (score 1):

You (nearly) can do that using the operator panel:

[image]

Comment: I think the main advantage of being able to navigate while in transform operation is that you could then use multiple snap points on more complex geometry a bit easier. This does not seem to be possible this way.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality does not exist in Blender 2.80. You can do that in [Mechanical Blender](http://www.mechanicalblender.org/static/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could set up multiple views in different windows before you start the editing process. This would allow you to see every angle whilst (a little Australian there for Andrew Price...) editing.

Answer (score 0):

you can

1. press `MID MOUSE BUTTON` or (`DOLLY`)
2. and dredge the mouse in any direction

When I finish rotating the 3d view release the button and continue working

[image: rotate view]

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers. I get it now.